# CircleCI app continuous building

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, yaml, circleci

I'm running a continuous integration on CircleCI and I'm getting the following error:

> Your build has exceeded the memory limit of 4G on 1 container. The
>   results of this build are likely invalid. We have taken a snapshot of
>   the memory usage at the time, which you can find in a build artifact
>   named `memory-usage.txt`. The RSS column in this file shows the amount
>   of memory used by each process, measured in kilobytes.

It gets stuck while doing this:

```
<=====--------> 40% EXECUTING [3m 33s]> :app:transformClassesWithStackFramesFixerForProdDebug> IDLE> IDLE> IDLE> IDLE> IDLE> IDLE> IDLE> IDLE> IDLE> IDLE> IDLE<=====--------> 40% EXECUTING [3m 34s]> :app:transformClassesWithStackFramesFixerForProdDebug > Resolve files of :app> :app:transformClassesWithStackFramesFixerForProdDebug> :app:transformClassesWithDesugarForProdDebug > Resolve files of :app:prodDebu> :app:transformClassesWithDesugarForProdDebug<=====--------> 40% EXECUTING [3m 35s]<=====--------> 40% EXECUTING [3m 36s]<=====--------> 40% EXECUTING [3m 37s]<=====--------> 40% EXECUTING [3m 38s]<=====--------> 40% EXECUTING [3m 39s]<=====--------> 40% EXECUTING [3m 40s]<=====--------> 40% EXECUTING [3m 41s]<=====--------> 40% EXECUTING [3m 42s]<=====--------> 40% EXECUTING [3m 43s]<=====--------> 40% EXECUTING [3m 44s]<=====--------> 40% EXECUTING [3m 45s]<=====--------> 40% EXECUTING [3m 46s]<=====--------> 40% EXECUTING [3m 47s]<=====--------> 40% EXECUTING [3m 48s]<=====--------> 40% EXECUTING [3m 49s]<=====--------> 40% EXECUTING [3m 50s]<=====--------> 40% EXECUTING [3m 51s]<=====--------> 40% EXECUTING [3m 52s]<=====--------> 40% EXECUTING [3m 53s]<=====--------> 40% EXECUTING [3m 54s]<=====--------> 40% EXECUTING [3m 55s]<=====--------> 40% EXECUTING [3m 56s]<=====--------> 40% EXECUTING [3m 57s]<=====--------> 40% EXECUTING [3m 58s]
```

(./gradlew assemble) died unexpectedly

I can't find anything useful in the `memory-usage.txt` file that has been created. I have looked it up and I found https://circleci.com/docs/1.0/oom/ but trying to include `GRADLE_OPTS: '-Dorg.gradle.jvmargs="-Xmx2048m -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError"'` in the `circleci.yml`config file actually makes the build crash with `Action failed: Configure the build``

Did anybody have the same problem?
Thanks in advance!